# Not getting focus for the ref in react

Tags: reactjs, focus

am not getting focus for the ref used

```
class SubPageHeader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.button = null;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
   this.button.current.focus();
  }
render(){
<Field domRef={ref=>this.button=ref}/>
}
```

using react verion 16.3. Tried with reactDOM.findDOMNode ,but it seems deprecated.

Comment: You need forward ref or its equivalent - https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: @GanapatiVS any handy example ,will be great?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-sound-02cc4

Comment: @GanapatiVS we are using the same, i had changed ref to forward ref,but no luck

Comment: You need to wrap `Field` component in `React.forwardRef`, check the demo carefully.